# ModelMapper map List<...> to object property

Tags: java, spring, modelmapper

I am struggling with mapping List into responseDTO.getList()

My code:

*MessageDTO*

```
 @Getter
 @Setter
 public Class MessageDTO() {
   private String message;
   ...
 }
```

*MessagesDTO*

```
@Getter
@Setter
public Class MessagesDTO() {
  private List<> message;
}
```

*MyConverter*

```
public class MyConverter extends AbstractConverter<List<MessageDTO>, MessagesDTO> {

    @Override
    protected ChatMessagesResponseDTO convert(List<MessageDTO> source) {
      MessagesDTO destination = new MessagesDTO();
      destination.setMessages(source);
      return destination;
    }
}
```

*Controller*

```
...
List<MessageDTO> messages = ... // result of service and succesfull mapping entity to dto
ModelMapper mm = new ModelMapper();
Converter conv = new MyConverter();
mm.addConverter(conv);
MessagesDTO messagesDTO = mm.map(messages, MessagesDTO.class)
return messagesDTO; // always null
```

Any ideas why it is not working ? I am sucessfuly using modelmapper in many other places of my project even with custom TypeMap(s) and Converter(s), but cannot find a way how to map list of some type into DTO attribute which is list of that type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because of type erasure. **ModelMapper** is unable to recognize the generic type of a `List` and thus does not apply your converter. I'm not sure if it is possible to achieve with classes you presented but if it is it might be quite complicated task.

One solution would be to declare class that has the type stored runtime. So like:

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public static class MessageDTOList extends ArrayList<MessageDTO> {};
```

and make required changes to your converter, so to be:

```
public class MyConverter extends AbstractConverter<MessageDTOList, MessagesDTO> {
    @Override
    protected MessagesDTO convert(MessageDTOList source) {
      MessagesDTO destination = new MessagesDTO();
      destination.setMessages(source);
      return destination;
    }
}
```

If it is hard to get the response directly as a `MessageDTOList` you can always:

```
List<MessageDTO> messages = ... // result of service and succesfull mapping entity
MessageDTOList messagesDerived = new MessageDTOList();
messagesDerived.addAll(messages);
```

and then just:

```
MessagesDTO messagesDTO = mm.map(messagesDerived, MessagesDTO.class);
```